# How to mix guitar and other source(laptop, mp3 player) into headphones?

Tags: guitar, mixing, headphones

This might get asked a lot but I find it difficult to search for an up-to-date answer and one that does not suggest using a laptop or something like a pod with digital amp modeling.

Basically I want to mix a backing track coming from a laptop or mp3 player with the signal coming from my amp into headphones. I want to retain the ability to use my existing setup with my pedals and I prefer not use a digital amp.

For headphones I plan of buying a beyerdynamic dt 770 pro 80 ohm. My amp has an out for headphones but I need a way to mix in songs that I want to play along to while wearing headphones.

What is an easy way to achieve this? I have looked at some options like a scarlett focusrite but I have no idea if this will actually help me achieve what I want.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are headphone mixing amps available also. I think Behringer makes a model.  Either way, a small mini mixer (two or four channel to one out) could be used to send a mix of your guitar and playback into your amp, and use the headphone out from the amp.

Comment: Actually bought a focusrite solo. Works absolutely perfect. Thanks for answering though.

Answer (score 0):

You have pretty much hit on the solution to this in your question.

You need a mixer of some kind. These range from incredibly cheap 2 -input, 1-output devices all the way up to multi track desks requiring major computer systems and amplification.

Just pick yourself up a mixer in your price bracket that has headphone out and all the inputs you want.

Comment: Do you have any good recommendations for a mixer? Or possible just some examples of mixers. I have no experience what-so-ever with them. Just pointing me in the right direction would help out a lot.

Comment: Sadly this isn't a recommendations site, but for what you need it doesn't matter. Just pick up a cheap one.

Comment: Really helpful...

Comment: @Stephan-v - what is really useful here is to upvote any posts that helped you, and to click on the check box next to the post that helped you the most, to assign it as the "accepted answer"

Answer (score 0):

If your amp has an AUX socket you can connect it to the laptop output while also connecting your headphones to the amp.